# Azure Rest API giving AuthorizationFailed error and invalid_request error

Tags: php, azure, curl, azure-active-directory

I have tried two different APIs from different articles as shown below.

**API 1**

[image]

This API is working and token is getting generated.

Then in next part of API I am using generated token to fetch data:

[image]

But it is giving following error as shown in screenshot also.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "AuthorizationFailed",
        "message": "The client '**************' with object id '**************' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Web/sites/read' over scope '/subscriptions/**************' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."
    }
}
```

**API 2**

[image]

But in this API, even token is not getting generated and giving following error

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "AADSTS901002: The 'resource' request parameter is not supported. Trace ID: ************ Correlation ID: ************ Timestamp: 2023-12-28 07:17:52Z",
    "error_codes": [
        901002
    ],
    "timestamp": "2023-12-28 07:17:52Z",
    "trace_id": "************",
    "correlation_id": "************"
}
```

I searched but couldn't find the solution. I want to fetch data from Azure active directory via Rest API. But that doesn't seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an **Azure AD application and granted API permissions** like below:

[image]

I generated **access token** using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
resource:https://management.azure.com
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

Using the above generated access token, I tried to call the API and got the **same error**:

```json
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites?api-version=2016-08-01
```

[image]

The error usually occurs if the Azure AD application doesn't have required permissions/roles to access the API.

**To resolve the error,** make sure to assign **`Reader` role** to the Azure AD application like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Subscriptions -> Select your subscription -> Access control (IAM) -> Add -> Add role assignment -> Select Reader ->  Select memebers -> Review and assign*

[image]

**Now generate the token again and you will be able to call the API successfully:**

*As I do not have any sites in my environment, I am getting empty results*

[image]

To generate access token to call the Microsoft Graph API, pass **`https://graph.microsoft.com`** as resource.

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
resource:https://graph.microsoft.com
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

- As you are using **v1 endpoint** to generate the access token then **resource** must be `https://management.azure.com` and `https://graph.microsoft.com` respectively.
- If you use **v2 endpoint** to generate the access token then you must pass **scope** as `https://management.azure.com/.default` and `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` respectively.

Comment: I assigned reader role to one of the user. But still getting same error. May be because API don't know to which user I have assigned reader role. I have many user/memeber. How API will know that which user has reader role. I think assign reader role to only one member out of many available might now be enough. What should I change?

Comment: @Rishabh You have to assign reader role to the Azure AD application by which you are generating token not the user

Comment: Damn it, I was doing this simple mistake. I did read similar solution earlier but I was selecting user to assign role, not app. This part worked perfectly. Now I will check your graph api solution too.

Comment: I did change resource "https://graph.microsoft.com" and created token. When I used token to `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subscription_id/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites?api-version=2016-08-01` then it is showing "AuthenticationFailed". I also tried to use graph token to this api url also `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` but that didn't work either. What mistake I am doing here?

Comment: You cannot use Graph API token to call `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subscription_id/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites?api-version=2016-08-01` as this is Azure management API

Comment: Yes, but I also used `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`. This should work I think.

Comment: To call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` api url you must grant User.Read.All application type API permission to the Azure ad application

Comment: Grant API permission like [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/ZYXTVEy.png)  make sure to grant admin consent and then generate the token and call this api `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`

Comment: I am checking, I will let you know as soon as its done :)

Comment: It's showing admin consent "yes" but in status column it showing warning. https://imgur.com/fu3Xonu

Comment: Ok, I think I need MPN ID to verify app so that he can gain access of showing users. Seems admin consent is not enough any more here. Thanks for all the help, really appreciated :)

Comment: You have not granted Admin consent to the Api permissions. The [**Grant Admin consent**](https://i.imgur.com/HRO1edx.png) is greyed out for you. You must be having either Global Administrator role to grant admin consent

Comment: Oh okay. Then I need to contact admin to grant permission or something I have to do on my end only?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256405/discussion-between-rukmini-and-rishabh).

Comment: Hi, I have posted one issue of similar api. Please check if you have time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77744020/authorization-requestdenied-error-on-https-graph-microsoft-com-v1-0-users

Comment: Sure I will check on that