# Authorization_RequestDenied error on https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

Tags: php, azure, curl, azure-active-directory

I am trying to fetch miscrosoft graph api user. For that I have generated token like this.

[image]

After getting token, I am using the token to fetch users using this api url

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

I have given all the needed permission to the API. but still getting following error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2024-01-02T02:54:50",
            "request-id": "******************",
            "client-request-id": "******************"
        }
    }
}
```

Admin consent also has been assigned to the application as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: To fetch the users, grant **`User.Read.All`** Application API permission not **`User.Export.All`** API permission. Check [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/HRO1edx.png)

Comment: @Rukmini It didn't work. I assigned admin consent to "User.Read.All" but error remain same.

Comment: Could you paste the screenshot of the API permissions after granting user.read.all?

Comment: @Rukmini I have updated screenshot in question. Please check.

Comment: You have to assign User.Read.All application permission not delegated permission. Let me know if that works I will post it as an answer

Comment: @Rukmini It worked with User.Read.All of Application. Thanks. Please post as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note** that: To fetch the users, the Microsoft Entra application must have **`User.Read.All`** Application API permission granted as you are making use of Client credential flow.

Make sure to grant **`User.Read.All`** Application API permission to the application:

[image]

I generated the **access token** by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
resource:https://graph.microsoft.com
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

By using the above token, **I am able to fetch the users successfully**:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[List users - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)

Comment: Hi, your answer is working fine but one question. API is only giving 100 users but when I go to all users page in portal.azure then it shows more than 100 there. Any idea why it is not showing all users?

Comment: Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/867523/how-to-get-more-than-100-azure-ad-users-from-speci

Comment: Just click on `@odata.nextLink` link like [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/lsd3PIv.png) as by default Microsoft Graph API fetches only 100 users.